# *through* vs. *tough*: ME*-ough* /uːx/ > –? How are the sound shifts from ME -ough explained?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, historical-linguistics, sound-change

How is it explained that the sound sequence /uːx/ *-ough* has developed so differently in different words?
Not-dipthongized in *through*, shortened and unrounded and retained fricative in *tough*, lowered in *though*, as you would expect in *plough*. (also a bit different in *ought*)

Are there regular sound shifts, do they stem from different dialects?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31991/why-does-the-ending-ough-have-six-pronunciations

Comment: You know more about this than I do. Look at Ger. *doch* "*though", and *durch* "through*, it seems that the lowering as you say was present at the root. I could see *borough* vs Ger. *Bereich* belong together; from a  Frank or AnglSax root? *barracks*? *trough* is far from "Traufe", I lexicalize it close to *Truhe* "case" instead; *Trog* is of course closer, silly me. What about *Docht* "wick (of candle)", does that have anything to do with *tough, wicked*? cp. *dough* vs "Teig", opposed to *Teich* "pond" /ç/ and **day** vs "Tag", LowGer. *Tach* /x/ (never /ç/ after /a/). cp. Sw. *ok, och*.

Comment: I mean they plainly couldn't spell in ye olde times. I suspect it was always different diphtongs and velars, if I compare the ambiguous state of German *ch* across the dialects. But I haven't studied old English.

Comment: Top related question "Was there a Semitic influence on Proto-Germanic?" lol

Comment: When the [x] allophone of final /h/ was being lost, some people said it and others didn't. And some people heard it and others heard something else. If you don't have a velar fricative in your language, what do you hear when somebody else does? Often enough people heard labial fricatives, and other times people heard an /h/, which they didn't pronounce any more. And not all long vowels shifted as ordered.

Comment: @vectory, "borough" and "Bereich" shouldn't be related. I assume *Bereich* is from the stem rīk- + the prefix *be-*. The stem of *borough* is just that *borough* and I'm sure it's related to *Burg*. And *tough* is related to *zäh*, Germanic *t* becomes a fricative or affricate depending on the position.

Comment: @jlawler Yes, some people dropped the /x/, but such changes are regular. So, it has to be assumed that either there is a cause for the /x/ to be completely dropped whilst being retained in some form in other words, or the two words differing in pronunciations have to come from different dialects. The question is if there is any evidence on how it exactly happened in this case.

Comment: @tobiornottobi: "Regular sound change' does not mean "sudden sound change". Words like "completely" and "regular" don't have any meaning during the period of a language change. These things take generations, and people vary in their takeup rate, as do words and sounds. "Regular" sound changes are always decided upon centuries after they've ended, with no witnesses still alive.

Comment: (again) @vectory 
"I mean they plainly couldn't spell in ye olde times." That's a good hint. Whilst this specific spelling came up relatively late, there are often several phonemes in these old languages that weren't distinguished in writing. After looking at the link above, I've come to the conclusion that at least some *ough* spellings must have always been distinct in pronunciation because they come from different vowels in Old English. It seems that many words with *ough* have never rhymed and that I just erroneously assumed that they were the same in Middle English.

Comment: @jlawler we have observed that phonemes change according to specific rules. If you can't find a rule that would make a sound shift regular that should be a very red flag. (The factors can also lie in the prosody etc.) It doesn't matter how long it took but a sound change that targets a phoneme leads to regular sound changes. Regardless of how long it takes, instances of the **same** phoneme in the **same** environment change at the same rate, that's what's important.

Comment: ...A red flag in that the irregular form is probably a loan word or that you haven't found the cause for the sound shift yet.

Comment: There's also hypercorrection affecting these phonemes in some dialects, e.g. Rhein- or Moselfrankigh [!] "elektrich" /ç/ instead of "elektrisch" /ʃ/ (cp. Dutch with /s/, En. with /k/), and elsewhere "komig" instead of standard "komisch", according to http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperkorrektur ... I thought it was a speech impediment, before I found out :) Just saying because *Tach* /x/ *dagaz "day" might be such a  case, for all I know. And, due to your comments I came to think "ch" really represented "c" /ʔ ~ k/ + "h" /h ~ x/ at one point, perhaps aspirated or even voiced  k, I don't know.

Comment: @vectory Germanic /x/ had been /x/ from the beginning of Germanic. The Roman alphabet didn't have a letter for this sound, so *h* and *ch* were used. In German, the high German consonant shift also shifted *k* to /x/ and in many West Germanic languages *ǥ* /ɣ/ was unvoiced to /x/ at least in final position. laχ- > *la/x/en* daǥ- > *Ta/x/*, brek- > *bre/x/en.

Comment: English lost the sound after the Middle English period, except for some very archaic dialects. A hypercorrection would be if you used /x/ in words that never had it.

Comment: *The Roman alphabet didn't have a letter for this sound, so h and ch were used* That's not a proper argument. Thinking about this, is *Lackmeier*, *der Gelackmeierte* related to *lachen*? I speculated it related to *Lake*, Sp. *leche* milk", e.g. the milkman, which doesn't quite check out because *Lake* is "brine", not milk. Also compare *Lache* "puddle", viz. *pool*, to pool together. Ger. *Puhlen* "to pick". viz. *pickled*

Comment: That's *pulen*, not *Puhlen*, sorry. I'd see a sense "to plug" if comparing it to *pickles* "sealed (plugged) food preservation", although *to plug ones nose* is not *to pick* (it's close enough). This brings us to *eingelegt* "pickled" . It's funny to note that *low* might as well be written *lough*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87750/discussion-between-tobiornottobi-and-vectory).

Comment: Which brings into question *verlorene Eier* "poached eggs". cp *verlieren* "to loose", *verlegt* "misplaced", *verlegen* "ashamed". It's not evidently conserved eggs (opposed to hundred years eggs), but *poach* has something of *bagged*, and ... *to last* somehow links to *leisten* "afford", PGem laistijaną "to pursue" (cp *purse* viz *poach*? *belagern* "(try) persuade"?). I'm saying it was *verlowene Eier"; cp *anlaufen* "get a (layer of) discoloration" (also "to try, prepare); *to lock* (viz *ausflocken* "denaturate", *flach*); *lügen* "to hide something. Ain't it fancy, not to say *posh*?

Answer (score 1):

The word "through" was spelled **thrugh** in Middle English. It derives from older **thurh**, i.e. the position of the 'r' has changed (metathesis). The "u" was short: Old English "þurh", whereas it was long in the word **tough, tou** from Old English "tōh".

The German word "durch" (through) is almost pronounced as Old English þurh and has a short "u" as well, whereas "zäh" (tough) has a long vowel (+umlaut), and the final 'h' is mute.